# the two buttons aren't in the same line

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make two buttons in the same line but there's a button it's position more lower than the other one; I used `inlne-block` in `.selection-btn` and It doesn't work although.

[image]

```css
.selection.btn {
  display: inline-block;
}

.authorize {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #6B2FFF;
  background-size: 0% 100%;
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: background-color .5s;
  padding: 0 45px;
  width: 275px;
  height: 60px;
}

.login {
  background-color: #7289DA;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0 27px;
  width: 275px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="selection-btn">
  <button class="authorize"><FontAwesomeIcon className="discord" icon={faDiscord} size="2x" />Add to Discord</button>
  <button class="login">Login</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you've pasted doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: vertical-align:top to your buttons

Comment: There is also a small issue with your css selector `.selection.btn` in your posted code. It should be `.selection-btn`

Comment: Removing your font-size style on authorize css will make the button have same size.